# Exact limit to avoid "Argument list too long "

Tags: unix, fedora, ulimit

I know that there are some tricks to avoid the shell's limit, which leads to "argument list too long", but I want to understand why the limit hits in my case (even though it should not). As far as I know the limit of chars in an argument for a command should be able to be determined by the following steps:

1. Get the maximum argument size by `getconf ARG_MAX`
2. Subtract the content of you environment retrieved by `env|wc -c`

On my machine with Fedora 30 and zsh 5.7.1 this should allow me argument lists with a length of up to 2085763 chars. But I already hit the limit with only 1501000 chars. What did I miss in my calculation?

---

Minimal working example for reproduction:

Setting up files:

```sh
$ for i in {10000..100000}; do touch Testfile_${i}".txt"; done
$ ls Testfile*
zsh: argument list too long: ls
```

No I deleted stepwise (1000 files per step) files to check when the argument line was short enough to be handled again

```sh
for i in {10000..100000..1000}; do echo $(ls|wc -l); rm Testfile_{$i..$((i + 1000))}.txt; ls Testfile_*|wc -l; done
```

The message `zsh: argument list too long: ls` stops between 79000 and 78000 remaining files. Each filename has a length of 18 chars (19, including the separating whitespace), so in total at this moment the argument line should have a total length of 79000*19=1501000 respectively 78000*19=1482000 chars.

This result is the same magnitude in comparison to the expected value of 2085763 chars but still it's slighty off. What could explain the difference of 500000 chars?

---

### ADDENDUM1:

Like suggested in the comments I ran `xargs --show-limits` and the output fits round about my expectation.

```sh
$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 4783 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2090321
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2085538
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

### ADDENDUM2:

Following the comment of @Jens I now added 9 Bytes additional overhead to the words (8 Bytes for the pointer, 1 for the terminating NUL-Byte). Now I get the following results (I do not know, how the whitespace is handled, for the moment I leave it out):
79000*(18+9)= 2133000
78000*(18+9)= 2106000

Both values are much closer to the theoretical limit than before...indeed, they are even a bit above it. So together with some safety margin I'm more confident to preestimate the maximal argument length.

---

### Further reading:

There are more posts about this topic, of which none answers the question in a satisfying way, but still they provide good material:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/211477
- https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: I recall there is usually a limit to the number "words" (as well as overall character count). Try searching for `Limits`. In some systems it is documented in the man page for the shell you are using. But guessing there may also be a `getconf` argument that will show that too. Sorry I don't have time to research that. Good luck.

Comment: @JannekS.: What does ` xargs --show-limits` say on your system about the _maximum length of a command_?

Comment: @JannekS : What is `getconf ARG_MAX` on your system? Your calculation seems to be odd. The ARG_MAX value itself should be the maximum number of parameters, which is more relevant than the maximum command length size. On my system, this is 32000.

Comment: @user1934428 I appended the output of `xargs --show-limits` to my post. `getconf ARG_MAX` returns on my system `2097152`. Did you really mean `ARG_MAX` because your value seems to me quite low...or maybe I misunderstand the meaning of this output

Comment: Wild guess: for each argument, a pointer needs to be in `char *argv[]`, and each string is NUL-terminated. With, say, 1000 words on a 64bit system, this adds 9000 bytes of overhead to the actual words. Did you take that into account?

Comment: @JannekS. Indeed, `ARG_MAX` seems to be the one which is applicable here, see forinstance [this explanation](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/). And, ARG_MAX of about 2 million seems to be quite a lot. On the page I linked to, you find near the bottom typical ARG_MAX values for various systems, and I am surprised that your `getconf`` reports such a high value.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the link, the content is really interesting..and I see now your concern with my value for ARG_MAX. I "appreciate" the statement _"The most reliable way to get the currently available space is to test the success of an exec() with increasing length of arguments until it fails."_

Comment: @Jens I did not consider this in my calculation and redid them, I'll edit my post according to this

Answer (score 0):

If you where looking to count files, this worked for me on Mac OSX Ventura (13.1)

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.zip" | wc -l
```

I had 1039999 zip files and the standard "ls */*.zip | wc -l" just died ("zsh: argument list too long: ls")